# Callback to Fragment from Activity started by a custom Adapter

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a Fragment that contains a ListView with a custom Adapter. When select a ListItem an other activity appears as a popup in which contents of selected items can be modified, OK?

Now there is a save button on new activity by clicking updated record is getting saved, Fine?

Now the problem is how to update the list so that changes can be made visible?

**FragmentClass.java**

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.my_listview);

Adapter adp = new Adapter(...);
lv.setAdapter(adp);
```

**Adapter.java**

```
....
....
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,PopupActivity.class);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

**PopupActivity.java**

```
//Save button clicked

//Update the listview in the fragment

finish();
```

Comment: you can call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: How and where to call? Means I'm currently in PopupActivity class

Comment: in `PopupActivity.java`,  call as : `adp.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: adp is not in PopupActivity, its in Fragment class

Comment: then you can call it in `onResume` of your fragment

Comment: Also tried, but onResume of Fragment is not getting fired :-(

Comment: How you Update the listview in the fragment in popUp activity??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61868/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-waqar-khan).

Comment: I don't know how to update, this is actually the question..
But i'm adding the record in listview by calling `PopupActivity` as startActivityForResult(..); in FragmentClass and updating listview on onActivityResult(..);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can notify the list with the use of `notifyDataSetChanged`

So call it in `OneResume`

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```